# how to change byte type in pythone

Tags: python, byte

i have a small problem and it caused me a lot of trubble. basicly i want to convert an immage to bytes than store string wersion of those bytes in an txt file and than read file contents and transform it into bytes and than into image. i've goten first part of this kinda ready (it works but it's made quickly and badly) but the conversion from string to byte gives me problem.
when i read image bytes it's something like this: b'GIF89aP\x00P\x00\xe3'
but when i read it from txt by 'rb' or just transform str to byte it gives me this: b'GIF89aP\\x00P\\x00\\xe3'
and with this i can't write it to an immage.
so i've tried to read and learn anything about this but i couldn't find anything that would help.

the code is here and i know it's really messy but i just need it to work

```
file = open('p.gif', 'rb')
image = file.read()
str_b = str(image)
leng = len(str_b)
print(leng)
str_b = str_b[:0] + str_b[0+2:]
leng =- 1
str_b = str_b[:leng]
print(image)

#a = open('bytearray', 'w+')
#a.write(str_b)
#a.close

a = open('bytearray', 'r')
a = a.read()
temp = a.encode('utf-8')
print(temp)
#b = open('check', 'w+')
#b.write(str(string))
#print(string)
image_result = open('decoded.jpg', 'wb') # create a writable image and write the decoding result
image_result.write(temp)
```

basicly my goal right now is to get bytes that look like this: b'GIF89aP\x00P\x00\xe3'

Comment: If a file contains binary information, you must open it it binary mode.  If you don't it will undergo text translation which will certainly change the contents in a way that won't be beneficial to you.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use eval like suggested above, eval has serious security vulnerabilities and will execute any python code you pass within it. You could accidentally read a text file that has code to reformat the disk and it will just execute, this is just an example but you get my point its bad practice and just results in more problems see https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html if you want some examples on why eval is bad

anyways lets try to fix your code

instead of converting your byte array to string by wrapping it in the str() method I would suggest you use .decode() and .encode()

Fixed Code:

```
with open('p.gif', 'rb') as file:
    image = file.read() # read file bytes

str_image = image.decode("utf-8") #using decode we changed the bytes to a string

with open('image.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(str_image) # write image as string to a text file

with open('image.txt', 'r') as file
    str_from_file = file.read() # read the text file and store the string

file_bytes = str_from_file.encode("utf-8")  # encode the image str back to bytes
print(type(str_from_file)) #type is str
print(type(file_bytes)) # types is bytes
```

I hope this fixes your issue and also doesn't include vulnerabilties in what your building

Comment: The `image.decode` is almost certainly going to throw an exception, because a gif file (or any other kind of image) isn't a character string and will contain invalid byte sequences.